# Applying php function to all html buttons with a specific ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter-2

Consider:

```
<input type="submit" id="edit" value="Edit" <?php echo button_access(1,'is_update') ?>>
```

The button_access function adds the "disabled" attribute to the button if the condition is true. Here is the php function:

```
// the function needs to access the session by codeigniter, so I can't use jquery
function button_access($module, $function) {
    $ci = &get_instance();
    return $ci->session->userdata['matrix'][$module][$function] == 0 ? 'disabled' : '';
}
```

The problem is I have lots of buttons with id="edit" all over several pages (one buton per page).

I would like to apply the button_access function to all html buttons with the id "edit". Is that possible? Is their  a better way aside from repeating it all over the code?

Comment: `lots of buttons with id="edit"` **ID should always be unique** use class instead or change the ID

Comment: he wrote that they are on different pages

Comment: Im assuming your "Over several pages" are including other pages as well?

Comment: @MuthaFury "Im assuming your "Over several pages" are including other pages as well?" - yes, I've thought about including a page with this function for all pages, but I don't know how php can manipulate buttons as jquery does. I feel it's not possible, but I hope I can find a way.

Comment: @guradio "lots of buttons with id="edit"" - one button per page.

Comment: @morbidCode place the code in footer ,it will be auto apply when the edit button comes

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use class and not id for many buttons, and give parameter as class:

```
<input type="submit" class="edit module_1 funtion_is_update" id="edit_1" value="Edit" />
```

You can fill parameters withs php:

```
<?php echo "<input class='edit module_$m function_$f' ... />  ";     ?>
```

And with jQuery you get all class edit click:

```
/* wait for page ready */
$( document ).ready(function() {


    /* click on button class = "edit" */
    $(".edit").click(function(){

        /* check another class as param */
        if ( $( this ).hasClass( "module_1" ) ) {

             /* module 1 */

            etc., if has class funtion_is_update -> 
               return $ci->session->userdata['matrix'][1][is_update] == 0 ? 'disabled' : '';

            (or extract like substring values from class)

        }
    });


    });
});
```